# How to Select in between row's record from tables in SQL 2008?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I wonder, is there any option like "Skip"(from LINQ) in SQL to select particular rows in a table.

I mean, in a table named "abcd". In that table  300 rows are there. but from that 300 rows i want to select rows from 233 to 300 or 233 to 258.

How to do this?? Please anyone help.

Comment: When you use the `Skip` operator in LINQ-to-SQL, it actually generates SQL code to execute it server-side.  You can verify this yourself with something like `Console.WriteLine(myContext.Entities.Skip(50).Take(10))`, and you'll see the auto-generated SQL code for skipping rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cte or derived table for this:

```
With cte as (
    Select col1, col2, row_number() over(order by sortColumn) as rn
    From table
)
Select * 
from cte 
Where rn >= 233
And rn <= 258
```